# How to hide textarea that have focus on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css

I use textarea as clipboard on [my project](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/android.php), and I try to make it work on Android. In order to make textarea function, I needed to set width and height of 10px. There is few options of hiding something but If I try to use any of them (like opacity 0 or clip) textarea don't work at all, I'v try to put black mask on top of it and make background and color black. But when textarea have focus on Andorid it's always visible and it's always white with black text.

Anybody know how can I make textarea disappear and still function on Android?

Comment: textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) ?

Comment: @RooMan it's not Java it's a webpage, I've included javascript, css and jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that accessible hide from jquery mobile work:

```
textarea {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);
}
```

width and height need to be set, it can't be 0:

```
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
```